# Как правильно реализовать передачу параметров в конструктор?

Tags: c#

Вопрос состоит в следующем:
имеем базовый класс с некими параметрами, который реализует интерфейс IOptions:

```
public interface IOptions
{
    int Fdis { get; set; }
}
public class BaseOptions : IOptions
{
    public int Fdis { get; set; }
}
```

Имеется ряд приборов, которые наследуют базовые настройки и добавляют свои уникальные свойства:

```
public class PhotoDeviceOptions : BaseOptions
{
    public int LightLevel { get; set; }
    public int LightColor { get; set; }
}

public class PhohoDeviceOptions : BaseOptions
{
    public bool NoiseMasking { get; set; }
    public int SoundWaveType { get; set; }
}
```

И также существует два класса, который используют эти настройки:

```
public interface IDeviceProcessor 
{
    void Process();
}
public class PhotoDeviceProcessor : IDeviceProcessor 
{
    public void Process()
    {
         // здесь нужно использовать PhotoDeviceOptions
         photoDevice.UpdateLightSettings();
    }
}
public class PhonoDeviceProcessor : IDeviceProcessor 
{
    public void Process()
    {
         // здесь нужно использовать PhonoDeviceOptions
         phonoDevice.UpdateSoundSettings();
    }
}
```

Как правильно реализовать передачу настроек в DeviceProcessor ? Мне в голову приходят только два варианта:

1. Передавать интерфейс IOptions и затем преобразовывать его в нужный тип:

   ```
    private PhotoDeviceOptions _options;

    public PhotoDeviceProcessor (IOptions options)
    {
        if(options is not PhotoDeviceOptions)
            throw new InvalidCastException(nameof(options));

        _options = options as PhotoDeviceOptions;
    }
   ```
2. Передавать тип настроек, соответствующих классу:

   ```
    private PhotoDeviceOptions _options;

    public PhotoDeviceProcessor (PhotoDeviceOptions options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }
   ```

Или есть более правильный способ реализации?

Comment: `public class BaseOptions` - должно быть `public class BaseOptions : IOptions`?

Comment: Ваш пример плохой, потому что `OptionsA` и `OptionsB` - идентичные классы, а следовательно их можно смержить в один. Далее то же самое с `CreatorA` и `CreatorB`. Это как бы не проблема, но замечание. Просто из-за такой сильной обфускации кода непонятна изначальная задача. Вы же зачем-то это дерево наследников реализуете, а вот зачем - непонятно. Оба представленных варианта решения выглядят странно, мне не кажется правильным ни даункаст, ни конкретная реализация. Смысл в абстракции, если требуется даункаст - теряется, так же он теряется, если вместо базового класса используется наследник.

Comment: 2-е. В первом варианте от проброса интерфейса вы ничего не получаете, только лишний код

Comment: Я бы предложил обобщение на уровне абстракции, но для текущего примера его нет смысла прикручивать. Давайте либо конкретный или почти конкретный код, либо дорабатывайте пример, чтобы смысл того что вы делаете, прослеживался.

Comment: @aepot Обновил пример. Задача состоит в том чтобы использовать в классе DeviceProcessor соответствующие настройки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал ответ до того как вы обновили пример, поэтому ответ будет абстрактный. :)

У вас есть несколько конкретных моделей данных, здесь будет пример одной, потому что для контраста я буду использовать примитивный тип в качестве второй.

```cs
public class MathArguments
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
}
```

У них нет общих интерфейсов, вообще ничего общего. Но могут быть и общие базовые типы, это не запрещается.

И есть вот такие интерфейсы.

```cs
public interface ICalculator
{
    double Calculate();
}

public interface ICalculator<T> : ICalculator
{
    T Args { get; }
}
```

И вот здесь начинается интересное.

Давайте к примеру посчитаем вот такое

```cs
Math.Sqrt(A + B);
```

С помощью моделей данных и абстракций.

Реализуем 2 раза интерфейс.

```cs
public class SumCalculator : ICalculator<MathArguments>
{
    public MathArguments Args { get; }

    public SumCalculator(MathArguments args)
    {
        Args = args;
    }

    public double Calculate()
    {
        return Args.A + Args.B;
    }
}

public class SqrtCalculator : ICalculator<double>
{
    public double Args { get; }

    public SqrtCalculator(double args)
    {
        Args = args;
    }

    public double Calculate()
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Args);
    }
}
```

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arguments = new MathArguments { A = 2, B = 2 };
    ICalculator sumCalc = new SumCalculator(arguments);
    double sum = sumCalc.Calculate();

    ICalculator sqrtCalc = new SqrtCalculator(sum);
    double result = sqrtCalc.Calculate();

    Console.WriteLine(result); // 2
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Быть может пример не совсем хороший, но подходит под ваши требования. Смысл примера в том, что можно использовать обычный интерфейс для вызова метода, например из коллекции классов этого типа. И обобщенный интерфейс, чтобы не было ошибок в реализации или был возможен проброс типа через другие обобщения.

К сожалению обобщений для конструкторов не существует, поэтому правильная реализация конструктора - на совести разработчика. Свойство `{ get; }` как бы намекает, что его можно задать только в конструкторе. Если вам не нужно публичное свойство, то и интерфейс с обобщением не потребуется.

Отсюда делаю вывод, что вариант `Передавать тип настроек, соответствующих классу:` более правильный.